# Default Shape key ID in Keying Set export files broken

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

I've found that the default Keying set that Blender exports from the Keying Set Panel, when you have shape keys added to the keyset - then it will pull the following error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

The solution is changing the shape key ID to the correct one:

```
# Keying Set: KeyingSet
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

# Keying Set Level declarations
ks = scene.keying_sets.new(idname="KeyingSet", name="Keyset_Name")
ks.bl_description = ""

ks.use_insertkey_needed = False
ks.use_insertkey_visual = False
ks.use_insertkey_xyz_to_rgb = True

# ID's that are commonly used

## This is the default in blender, and it is broken. 
#id_0 = bpy.types.key["Key"]

### Use this instead:
id_0 = bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys

# Path Definitions
ksp = ks.paths.add(id_0, 'key_blocks["Shape_Name"].value', index=-1)
```

Comment: Bug reported: https://developer.blender.org/T52401

Comment: Fixed : https://developer.blender.org/rB743bacaa6f4e7dd4b621b8b908513ea6ce7b18e4